# How to show git author name in Sublime Text editor?

Tags: git, annotations, sublimetext

I'm using [GitGutter](http://www.jisaacks.com/gitgutter) with Sublime Text editor.

With this plug-in Git > This file > blame will open a new tab with annontations.

Is there any way to show the Git annotations in the same edit window probably just before the line number

Comment: How is this off topic? It's about tools commonly used by programmers.

Comment: Those who voted to close this question are adviced to revise the SO [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) again, it clearly says `question generally covers... software tools commonly used by programmers ...then you’re in the right place to ask your question!`

Comment: Don't know if you will see this but it probably isn't in ST2. What you can place in the gutter right now is very limited (essentially just icons). Granted I haven't used that plugin before, but though it would be worth mentioning, even with the "closed" status.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Ok a couple things here.

First off, The `git blame` feature is not a part of my [**GitGutter**](https://github.com/jisaacks/GitGutter) plugin, it is a part of the [**Git**](https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-2-git) plugin.

Secondly, @skuroda is correct that you can only put an icon in the gutter.

What you can do to simulate this tho: is use the split pane **View > Layout > Columns: 2** and put the git blame on the left pane and the actual file on the right pane. You will want to turn off word wrap **View > Word Wrap**

Here is a screen shot:
[image]

---

Then your only problem is to keep the 2 views in sync when you scroll. I haven't tested it but it looks like this sublime plugin might do that: [glue views](https://bitbucket.org/theblacklion/sublime_plugins/commits/3ea0c9e35d2f/#chg-glue_views.py)

Comment: Got 404 on the `glue views` link. Is it the same as https://gluedocs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ ?

Comment: I would add that nowadays GitGutter provides *Line Annotation*; those allows to visualise (without additional views) the same info ([configurable](http://jisaacks.github.io/GitGutter/settings/#line-annotation)) that `git blame` provides. Thanks man, really useful! 

Answer (score 44):

### Use Sublime Text Package [Git](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Git) and Command `Git: Blame`.

#### Install [Git](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Git) Package:

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

`Package Control: Install Package`

[image: Package Control: Install Package]

#### Use `Git: Blame` Command:

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

`Git: Blame`

[image: Git: Blame]

#### Result

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: 'Package Git' and command 'Git:blame' are the answer. Link is for quick find of "Package Git".

Comment: Thank you Josh for extending answer.

Comment: I am using Sublime Text 3 (Build 3103), and tried installing the 'Git' package  mentioned here through Package Control, but I couldn't find any hits for just 'Git'. I see a lot of entries beginning with 'Git', but no matches for just 'Git'. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @maverick first you have to `Shift + Command + P` click on package install and then search for `git blame`, I am guessing you are looking for git blame as soon as you click `Shift+Command+P`

Answer (score 2):

Rubymine (and presumably IntelliJ as well) has an `annotate` feature that looks like this:

[image]

JD Isaacks answer above is the closest I've seen to this, but I don't think Sublime Text 3 has such a feature without a lot of fiddling (as he describes).  Vscode has something similar, an "annotate" extension.

Comment: For `vscode` I was able to get something similar to the Rubymine look using the `gitlens` extension and then customizing it with these in the settings JSON: ``"gitlens.blame.dateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD", "gitlens.blame.format": "${date} ${author|14}"` -- then we activate the annotation side panel with the "toggle file blame" button.

Comment: As of February 2021 there is still no satisfactory way to do this in Sublime Text.